# Cursor Position between close and open tags

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know if it is possible to set caret between closed HTML tag and opened HTML tag.

This is my HTML:

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
  <div> Hello
    <span style="color: red;"> Foo </span>
    <span style="color: blue;"> 
      Bar 
      <span style="color: green;"> 
        From Baz 
      </span> 
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, if the cursor is at the end of green tag `<span style="color: green;">From Baz</span>` (how to get if cursor position at the end of the anchorNode?), by pressing right arrow key, it moves to the parent span which has blue color.

Even with using `setStart` on range variable at the beginning of the green span,it sets the cursor to the end of the blue span (`Bar`), then with writing it will be blue (expected was to be on the beginning of the green span).

The question is, is it possible to control cursor position between the tags or not?

**Update**

1 - I need pure Javascript solution.
2 - It also behaves differently depending on browser. So, it needs a solution that only depends on Javascript, in other word, the question will be, "How it is possible to take control of cursor?"

Comment: While browsers allow you to have a cursor in a fashion, I would have thought that this functionality would be very browser specific and likely not accessible.  Cursors within enter-able elements (eg. input, textarea) is a different matter and you can get at that info.  Perhaps to do what you want, you will need to use mouse events to get an initial position and key events to determine where that cursor is moved to.  I don't see it as being a simple task to do though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Graham the problem is not getting initial information with keypress or   mouse events, but to be able to move them between closed tag and open tags. And also, I do not want to add nbsp  charterer to make space between tags. 
The div with contentEditable="true" shows only the rendered HTML on the browser and moving the cursor is somehow impossible task to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach with `zero width non-joiner` (`&zwnj;`) character is used. it solves the problem but adds an extra character which doesn't change the looks but has a problem when using arrows to move caret left and right, hope it helps.

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
  <div> Hello
    <span style="color: red;">Foo </span>
    <span style="color: blue;">&zwnj;Bar
      <span style="color: green;">&zwnj;From Baz</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

Here is another approach which doesn't have the problem above:

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
  <div> Hello<span style="color: red;">
    Foo</span><span style="color: blue;">
    Bar<span style="color: green;">
    From Baz</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit 2

You could also do the following using Javascript:

```js
function RemoveSpaces(myQuery, parentNodeName){
  var myElement = document.querySelector(myQuery);
  var iterator = document.createNodeIterator(myElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, node => {
    if (node.parentElement.nodeName == parentNodeName) {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
  });
  
  var toBeRemoved = [];
  let next = iterator.nextNode();
  while(next) {
    toBeRemoved.push(next);
    next = iterator.nextNode();
  }

  toBeRemoved.forEach(n => RemoveFunction(n));
}

function RemoveFunction(c){
    if (!c.nodeValue.replace(/\s/g, '').length){
     c.remove();
    }
    else{
     c.nodeValue = "\n" + c.nodeValue.trim();
    }
}


RemoveSpaces('div[contenteditable="true"] div', 'DIV');
RemoveSpaces('div[contenteditable="true"] div', 'SPAN');
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
  <div>Hello
    <span style="color: red;"> Foo </span>
    <span style="color: blue;"> 
      Bar 
      <span style="color: green;"> 
        From Baz 
      </span> 
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit 3

For the issue mentioned in the comments, we can combine the first approach (`&zwnj;`), with the third approach which was JS.
So the idea is to add `&zwnj;` after each child span, so we can use its weakness (which was adding an invisible space which needed an extra right arrow) as its strength, so when the user hits the right arrow at the end of the green span, he would go after the `&zwnj;` character which is in the parent (blue) span.

so the HTML which we are generating should look like this:

```
<div>
Hello<span style="color: red;">
Foo</span>&zwnj;<span style="color: blue;">
Bar<span style="color: green;">
From Baz</span>&zwnj;</span>&zwnj;</div>
```

And This is the complete code to achieve that:

```js
function RemoveSpaces(myQuery, parentNodeName){
  var myElement = document.querySelector(myQuery);
  var iterator = document.createNodeIterator(myElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, node => {
    if (node.parentElement.nodeName == parentNodeName) {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
  });

  var toBeRemoved = [];
  let next = iterator.nextNode();
  while(next) {
    toBeRemoved.push(next);
    next = iterator.nextNode();
  }

  toBeRemoved.forEach(n => RemoveFunction(n));
}
function RemoveFunction(c){
  if (!c.nodeValue.replace(/\s/g, '').length){
    c.remove();
  }
  else{
    c.nodeValue = "\n" + c.nodeValue.trim();
  }
}


RemoveSpaces('div[contenteditable="true"] div', 'DIV');
RemoveSpaces('div[contenteditable="true"] div', 'SPAN');

//Added Code

var childrenspans = document.querySelector("div[contenteditable='true']").getElementsByTagName("span");
var newNode = document.createTextNode('\u200c');
childrenspans[childrenspans.length-1].parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, childrenspans[childrenspans.length-1].nextSibling);
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
  <div>Hello
    <span style="color: red;"> Foo </span>
    <span style="color: blue;"> 
      Bar 
      <span style="color: green;"> 
        From Baz 
      </span> 
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note that we are using `'\u200c'` instead of `'&zwnj;'`, it's because of the `createTextNode`, and we have to use it's Unicode which is `u200c`.

### Edit 4

As mentioned in the comments, The Edit 3 code works but after adding text after the green span, it would have the same problem as before with the first approach
which means there is an extra `&zwnj;` in the middle of the texts.

We can track inputs every time user inputs something, and we can remove the `&zwnj;` character if it's beside a space character.

It doesn't completely fix it, but helps.
Here is the code:

```js
function RemoveSpaces(myQuery, parentNodeName){
  var myElement = document.querySelector(myQuery);
  var iterator = document.createNodeIterator(myElement, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, node => {
    if (node.parentElement.nodeName == parentNodeName) {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
  });

  var toBeRemoved = [];
  let next = iterator.nextNode();
  while(next) {
    toBeRemoved.push(next);
    next = iterator.nextNode();
  }

  toBeRemoved.forEach(n => RemoveFunction(n));
}
function RemoveFunction(c){
  if (!c.nodeValue.replace(/\s/g, '').length){
    c.remove();
  }
  else{
    c.nodeValue = "\n" + c.nodeValue.trim();
  }
}


RemoveSpaces('div[contenteditable="true"] div', 'DIV');
RemoveSpaces('div[contenteditable="true"] div', 'SPAN');


var childrenspans = document.querySelector("div[contenteditable='true']").getElementsByTagName("span");
var newNode = document.createTextNode('\u200c');
childrenspans[childrenspans.length-1].parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, childrenspans[childrenspans.length-1].nextSibling);



//Added Code

function saveCaretPosition(context){
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    range.setStart(  context, 0 );
    var len = range.toString().length;

    return function restore(x){
        var pos = getTextNodeAtPosition(context, len);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        var range = new Range();
        if(x)
          range.setStart(pos.node ,pos.position-1);
        else
          range.setStart(pos.node ,pos.position);
        selection.addRange(range);
    }
}
function getTextNodeAtPosition(root, index){
    var lastNode = null;
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,function next(elem) {
        if(index >= elem.textContent.length){
            index -= elem.textContent.length;
            lastNode = elem;
            return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT
        }
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    });
    var c = treeWalker.nextNode();
    return {
        node: c? c: root,
        position: c? index:  0
    };
}

function RemoveCharCodeIfBesideCharacter(str, charCode, besideCharacter){
  function SortNumber(a, b) {return a - b;}
  var indexesToRemove = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   var strchar = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if(strchar == charCode && i != 0 && i != str.length-1){
      if(str.charAt(i-1) == besideCharacter || str.charAt(i+1) == besideCharacter)
        indexesToRemove.push(i);
    }
  }
  indexesToRemove.sort(SortNumber);
  var removeCount = 0;
  for(var i=0; i < indexesToRemove.length; i++){
   str = str.slice(0, indexesToRemove[i]-removeCount) + str.slice(indexesToRemove[i]+1-removeCount);
    removeCount++;
  }
  return str;
}

document.querySelector("div[contenteditable='true']").addEventListener("input", function() {
    var restore = saveCaretPosition(this);
    var before = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = RemoveCharCodeIfBesideCharacter(this.innerHTML, "8204", " ");
    restore(before != this.innerHTML);
}, false);
```

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
  <div>Hello
    <span style="color: red;"> Foo </span>
    <span style="color: blue;"> 
      Bar 
      <span style="color: green;"> 
        From Baz
      </span> 
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the best answer, that's why I upvoted. However, he now made an edit asking for a JS only solution.

Comment: You could use non-breaking space &nbsp; instead of &zwnj; . It would resolve problem

Comment: @Jiml ```&zwnj;``` is an invisible and zero width character but ```&nbsp;``` is a visible space which is unbreakable ```(non-breaking space)```, it means using ```&nbsp;``` instead of normal spaces would cause the paragraph not adjusting to width of parent element, but using normal space along with ```&zwnj;```, would solve the problem and the adjusting problem with ```&nbsp;```.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MohammadZamanian this is really interesting. I have not play with your solution. My main problem is the last span tag (Green span nested in Blue). Do you think it is possible to add event listener (right arrow for example) to get out the Green tag and continue right in the blue span? (or press another right arrow to go to the parent?). The problem I have that I could not set cursor after green span closing tag to continue writing in parent element.

Comment: @m.akbari done, but after adding text after the green span, it would have the same problem as before with the first approach, but it's actually a feature determining the line between colors.